# How to add a python program to a web project?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I have this code that detects face and eyes ( face recognition ) and it runs in python and appears in pycharm when it run as a cam window ,so I am asking how to add this window as a part of a web page project that is written in html css and javascript so it appear as a part of the web page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to use the Flask or Django lib for python to do this. More info about Flask can be read on their website: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/
I've never tried Flask with JavaScript, but I do know that python is the better than for example PHP

Comment: He's asking to integrate a window for cam to capture images